# Angular2 item with ngIf flickers

Tags: javascript, angular

**Background**

I am creating a credit card form component. The component checks which credit card type has been entered, and shows a symbol/icon of the card type. The symbol is an external SVG that loads as soon as the credit card type has been identified.

**Problem**

The cc-symbol flickers, as you can see in the image below. A look in the Chrome DOM inspector shows me that something is going on with the element with the `*ngIf` applied to it, the element is being updated somehow (without any attributes changing) which seems to cause the flickering.

[image: Angular2 ngIf flickering]

**Code**

Below is the code for the part of my template that contains the flickering part. I've checked the component and the variable used in `ngIf` isn't updated except when it's suppose to (when the credit card number is change to a one of different type).

```
<div class="credit-card-icon" *ngIf="creditCardType != null">
    <object type="image/svg+xml" [data]="getTypeIconUrl()"></object>
</div>
```

*What could be causing this issue, and how would I resolve it?*

**UPDATE**

It turns out that this is actually caused by the `[data]` attribute rather than having anything to do with `ngIf`. Sorry for blaming you, ngIf.

Comment: My take is that `getTypeIconUrl()` is called each time your form changes. I don't what's in there, but it looks like it takes some milliseconds to be performed. I think that you won't have the flickering if you used a simple `img` with a png or so.

Comment: It would kind of make sense if the form was changed, but the flickering keeps going on even after finishing typing. Look at the GIF in my post and you'll see! Also, using an `img` tag wouldn't help, since it's the outer `div` that flickers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After writing this post it got me thinking about why it would try to update the DOM element `object` all the time. Turns out the solution was pretty obvious. Since the issue didn't occur with a static `data`-attribute, but only with a dynamically bound `[data]`-attribute, I guessed it had something to do with object equality.

In my component I use the `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url)` method of `DomSanitizer` to "approve" the url of the icon.

However, the following statement is always false:

```
bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url) == bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url)
```

By caching the `SafeResourceUrl` returned from `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url)` this issue is resolved!